# Unexplained constant weight gain

Tags: diet, body-fat, bellyfat

My weight has been constantly increasing for the past 2 weeks at about a total of 6kg.. and i am very worried.

I used to be much leaner and could have tons of food without putting on much weight (stopped consuming meat products) and without exercising.

I understand that the human body will see a change for +- 2kg. However, in recent times, my weight seems to be on a increasing spree where everything i eat seems to directly increase my final weight and it never goes down and I can see and feel my body getting bigger and putting more pressure on my legs and it is never going down even when i went for runs every night..

I am having my exam phase now and I wonder if it could be due to it.. however, it has never been like that in the past.

Could someone advise me what i should do? Its really worrying me..

Comment: "I'm worried about my health. I know, to the interwebs! Screw them trained doctor types". If you are worried, go see a doctor.

Comment: 6kg in 2 weeks is outside of normal weight creep that I'd recommend seeing a doctor. Its probably nothing and as soon as your start tracking a(and reducing) your calories your weight will stabilise.

Comment: When you say stopped consuming meat products, are you saying you stopped having lunch meats or all meat entirely (i.e. vegetarian)?  Also, are you sure you are consuming enough protein, and your calories are in check?

Answer (score 1):

Your reliance on "going for some runs at night" makes me think you're not focusing on diet and nutrition.

Track your calories, drop most of the carbs, stength train, get a physical sport/hobby, and up the protein.

It's a lot of life modifications but it's the only long term path I know of that works.

Welcome to getting older.

Answer (score 0):

You really should state your age when asking such a question. If you're still growing, we will have to take a different approach towards guiding you, than is the case if you're fully grown.

If you're an adult, it's really quite simple:

- If you consume **fewer** calories (energy) than you burn (through exercise etc), then you will **lose** weight
- If you consume **as many** calories as you burn, then your weight will stay **the same**
- If you consume **more** calories than you burn, then you will **gain** weight

So simply go through your calorie intake and your physical activity during a normal day, and you will know why you gain weight.

If the above doesn't add up for you, go see a doctor - you might be retaining water or something worse.